# CDF of Mixture of Two Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

$\mathbb{P}(Z=X)=\alpha$ and  $\mathbb{P}(Z=Y)=1-\alpha$, i.e. $Z$ is a mixture of two random variables $X$ and $Y$. I am stuck in the application of the law of total probability to show that $F_Z(z)=\alpha F_X(z)+(1-\alpha)F_Y(z)$:

$$F_Z(z)=\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z)=\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z|Z=X)\mathbb{P}(Z=X)+\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z|Z=Y)\mathbb{P}(Z=Y)=\alpha\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z|Z=X)+(1-\alpha)\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z|Z=Y)=\alpha\mathbb{P}(X\leq z|Z=X)+(1-\alpha)\mathbb{P}(Y\leq z|Z=Y)$$.

Dropping the conditioning is obviously not allowed, and writing the definition of conditional probability makes it look weirder.
I feel using the "substitution law" is trickier than what I wrote here.

Comment: Why it is not allowed $\mathbb{P}(X\leq z|Z=X)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq z)$. 

The relationship you give can be written as

$ Z|(X,Y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ c l }
X,   &    a  \\
Y,   &    1-a
\end{array}
\right..$

Comment: But let us write the definition of conditional probability:

$$\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z|Z=X)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z,Z=X)}{{P}(Z=X)}$$ 

Why can we say 

$$\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z,Z=X)=\alpha\mathbb{P}(X\leq z)$$

Comment: $Z$ is smaller or equal than z, when $Z=X$ is true , so that means that $X$ is smaller or equal than z.$\{Z\leq z|Z=X\}=\{X\leq z\}$.